# Keyboard shifting page causes problems with inputs

Tags: ios, cordova

Ok so when you select an input in a phonegap/cordova project, the keyboard appears.  This pushes the page up, which is fine.  But, on ios devices, when you cause a touch event (say trying to select a dropdown) the mouseDown event causes the input to lose focus, which means the keyboard is dismissed.  This causes the page to move... and then the mouseUp event is fired, usually not where you started to click.

Is there a way to stop the keyboard from being dismissed on a mouseDown/touchStart event?  Or perhaps a way to prevent the keyboard dismissal from moving the page?  Or even a workaround with the click events to fix the problem.

We're using Cordova 1.7 and Jquery 1.6.4

Comment: UPDATE: This is not the default behavior.  From what I've learned the input will only lose focus if you try to touch/click somewhere that can gain focus.  I think yet again our problem has to do with us using iFrames.  I'll do some testing to confirm, see if I can find a work around, and post whatever I find out.

Comment: UPDATE 2: Ok, so I built a test case and found that just using frames didn't cause any problems.  I then narrowed down the pages that were having the problem and determined that the difference between those pages were that they had jQuery Validation and Mobiscroll in use.  Turns out that the validation adds logic for when users try to leave inputs (causing the problem) and Mobiscroll causes the problem when it's in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue when developing an cordova 2.0 app of my own.

Since i did need all kinds of logic on all kinds of touch events in my app, i couldn't just attempt to delete any libraries, so i've tried some creative approaches mostly revolving about messing with what happens to the touchstart-touchend-click process during each event.

None of this worked, but then i decided to try this:

```
$('.formClass .item-text input').bind('focus', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Which somehow worked with an obvious caveat that **i have no idea why**.

This approach might (no longer) be useful to you, since you seem to have solved the issue by excising some libraries; however, i'll hope somebody else who stumbles on this will have an easier day.